# operation of the "image" and "pcolor" function in matlab for visualizing matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, visualization, matlab-figure

I have matrices which I wish to visualize to get a feel for the values they contain. But the function [image](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/image.html) which I use by default gives a poor result. I have to scale the matrix manually with an appropriate value before the visualization is suitable.
my matrices scaled by value 1:[image: my matrix scaled by value 1]

```
image(Breceive(1+(ii-1)*20:20+(ii-1)*20,:)*1)
```

my matrices scaled by value 10[image: my matrix scaled by value 10]

```
image(Breceive(1+(ii-1)*20:20+(ii-1)*20,:)*10)
```

my matrices scaled by value 50[image: my matrix scaled by value 50]

```
image(Breceive(1+(ii-1)*20:20+(ii-1)*20,:)*50)
```

my matrices scaled by value 10000[image: my matrix scaled by value 10000]

```
image(Breceive(1+(ii-1)*20:20+(ii-1)*20,:)*10000)
```

my matrices with value 10000 added[image: my matrix with value 10000 added]

```
image(Breceive(1+(ii-1)*20:20+(ii-1)*20,:)+10000)
```

but using function [pcolor](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/pcolor.html) the scaling or addition does not change the presented matrices' colorings regardless of the value[image: pcolor result] But actually we see that a different number of rows get colored (6 here but 7 before)

```
pcolor(Breceive(1+(ii-1)*20:20+(ii-1)*20,:))
```

I thought that **image** should be scale invariant? That it normalizes the data beforehand. Can **pcolor** be trusted that it is doing a proper scale translation to color values? Is there some parameter or way to make **image** be stable? And why is pcolor not plotting the same information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image(C)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/image.html) uses the elements of C to directly index the figure's colormap.

[pcolor(C)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/pcolor.html) linearly scales the elements of C to fill the figure's colormap then indexes them.

You can use [imagesc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html) to produce a scaled image which will be invariant in the same way as pcolor.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Worked like a charm. One thing though, why did pcolor give different results??

Comment: I am surprised that they are different.  Internally imagesc(X) calls image(X, ... 'CDataMapping', 'scaled') and pcolor(X) calls surface(..., X) which defaults to having CDataMapping => scaled too.